# Download FLV video

Tags: c#, download, flv

I am making a program that helps me download whole seasons of anime from crunchyroll (Legally, of course) for private use, since my internet connection goes down on the regular.
I know its and FLV but I am not sure how to extract it from the video.
http://www.crunchyroll.com/hunter-x-hunter/episode-36-a-big-debt-x-and-x-a-small-kick-592035
Here is an example video, can someone walk me through what I should do/need?
Finding the ID/Signature/whatever will be easy since I have some experience with XPath
Thank you

Edit: http://www.crunchyroll.com/xml/?req=RpcApiVideoPlayer_GetStandardConfig&media_id=592035&video_format=0&video_quality=0&auto_play=1&click_through=1

I hope this can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download video, go use "[rtmpdumphelper](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/rtmp_dump_helper.html)".Crunchyroll uses RTMP streaming protocol to stream videos. RTMP dump does the job. Besides, there is already a tool out on internet that lets you rip those videos separately,though.Here is that tool's [official thread](http://www.darkztar.com/forum/showthread.php?219034-Ripping-videos-amp-subtitles-from-Crunchyroll-(noob-friendly)).
That is how to rip a single episode from crunchyroll.This is for windows.If you want to develop something for UNIX based OS. Use rtmpdump instead.